# After server restore, Content Porter and Template Builder stop working

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009, template-builder

I had to restore a virtual Tridion CM Server from a snapshot. When this was done, both the Content Porter and the Template Builder stop working. Everything else looked fine.

Both tools threw errors as soon as I tried to connect to the Tridion CM server in question.
Digging deeper, I found the following message in the Content Porter client log:

```
4/21/2016 2:18:24 PM    [Critical]  Server was unable to process request. ---> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\50bewxgf.0.cs' could not be found
error CS2008: No inputs specified
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.InvokeAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult result)
```

A similar message was displayed in the template builder

On a whim I changed the security settings on the Windows\Temp folder and gave everyone modify rights. This solved the problem rightaway!
What makes it stranger: when I later removed the extra permissions from the Windows\Temp folder, the problems did NOT come back.

Can anyone explain what happened here?